# Copy text to clipboard on click

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I've made a presentation with PP with some pictures and additional informations if you click on the picture. I like to have the functionality, that the content of these additional information popups will be automatically copied to clipboard with the click.

I guess I've to use VBA but don't know much about it ...

Comment: Yes it can be done using VBA, But anyone who wants to help you would like to see what kid of Pop Ups you are talking about. And besides this is not a Free Coding site, you have to try stuff yourself and if you are stuck somewhere you can post a question. Start by Googling your Problem.

Comment: Okay, I understand ...

Here is my solution so far:
`Sub test()
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Copy
End Sub`
Seems to work, but I've problems to identify the shape-number ...
Kai